# Using GetSchemaTable() to retrieve only column names

Tags: c#, sql

Is it possible to use `GetSchemaTable()` to retrieve only column names?

I have been trying to retrieve Column names (only) using this method, is it possible.

```
  DataTable table = myReader.GetSchemaTable();

  foreach (DataRow myField in table.Rows)
  {
      foreach (DataColumn myProperty in table.Columns)
      {
          fileconnectiongrid.Rows.Add(myProperty.ColumnName + " = " 
                            + myField[myProperty].ToString());
      }
  }
```

This code retrieves a lot of table data unwanted, I only need a list containing 
column names!:

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to use [`ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wy5a0f%28v=vs.100%29):

```
DataTable schema = null;
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    using (var schemaCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var reader = schemaCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))
        {
            schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
        }
    }
}
```

[SchemaOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior%28v=vs.100%29):

> The query returns column information only. When using SchemaOnly, the
>   .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server precedes the statement
>   being executed with SET FMTONLY ON.

The column name is in the first column of every row. I don't think that it's possible to omit the other column informations like `ColumnOrdinal,ColumnSize,NumericPrecision` and so on since you cannot use `reader.GetString` but only `reader.GetSchemaTable` in this case.

But your loop is incorrect if you only want the column names:

```
foreach (DataRow col in schema.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ColumnName={0}", col.Field<String>("ColumnName"));
}
```

Comment: Still returns all data :-( maybe something wrong with my loop.

Comment: @user1495962: The column name is in the first column of every row. I don't think that it's possible to omit the other column informations like `ColumnOrdinal,ColumnSize,NumericPrecision` etc. **Edited my answer**

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to below if all you want is to display the column names. Your original code was trying to not only display column names, but also trying to display the actual data values as well.

```
DataTable table = myReader.GetSchemaTable();

foreach (DataRow myField in table.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn myProperty in table.Columns)
    {
        fileconnectiongrid.Rows.Add(myProperty.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: tr yid setting it with no luck

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all column names, you can place them in a `string[]` and do with them what you like.

```
foreach(var columnName in DataTable.Columns)
{
  Console.WriteLine(columnName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Retrieve column schema into a DataTable.
schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();

int index = schemaTable.Columns.IndexOf("ColumnName");
DataColumn columnName = schemaTable.Columns[index];

//For each field in the table...
foreach (DataRow myField in schemaTable.Rows)
{
    String columnNameValue = myField[columnName].ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("ColumnName " + columnNameValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use same technics to add `MAX-STRING-LENGTH` constraint on **custom** `TextBox` in my VB.Net program.

I use a SQL `SELECT` command to get 4 column's values

```sql
    SELECT code_pays
          ,nom
          ,code_pays_short
          ,default_devise
      FROM pays
      ORDER BY nom
```

I use the result returned by an `IDataReader` object to fill a `DataGridView`.

And finally, I display each row's field in a `Panel` that contains 4 `TextBox`.

To avoid that SQL `UPDATE` command used to save some record's changes done in TextBox return error message due to column value too long, I have added a property in custom Textbox to inform directly user that value's size is overlapped.

Here is my Form

[image]

Here is VB.Net code used to initialize `MaxStringLength` properties

```vbnet
    Private Sub PushColumnConstraints(dr As IDataReader)
        Dim tb As DataTable = dr.GetSchemaTable()
    
        Dim nColIndex As Integer = -1
    
        For Each col As DataColumn In tb.Columns
            If col.ColumnName = "ColumnSize" Then
                nColIndex = col.Ordinal
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    
        If nColIndex < 0 Then
            oT.ThrowException("[ColumnSize] columns's index not found !")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    
        txtCodePays.MaxStringLength = tb.Rows(0).Item(nColIndex)
        txtPays.MaxStringLength = tb.Rows(1).Item(nColIndex)
        txtShortCodePays.MaxStringLength = tb.Rows(2).Item(nColIndex)
        txtDefaultDevise.MaxStringLength = tb.Rows(3).Item(nColIndex)
    End Sub
```

In `For` loop, program search index of field contained in `ColumnSize` column's value.

MaxStringLength property is assigned using following syntax

```
tb.Rows(%TEXT-BOX-INDEX%).Item(nColIndex)
```

`.Rows(%TEXT-BOX-INDEX%)` is used to identify **column's** metadata in SQL SELECT !

`.Item(nColIndex)` is used to get a specific column's metadata value

Item(n) can return a String or an Integer but VB.Net do implicit conversion when necessary.

This line of code can also be written shortly

```
tb.Rows(%TEXT-BOX-INDEX%)(nColIndex)
tb(%TEXT-BOX-INDEX%)(nColIndex)
```

but it is not readable !

Caution: `MaxStringLength` is a custom property. It is not part of normal TextBox.

In print screen above, you can see that program indicates to user that length is too big for `Code Pays (3 lettres)` TextBox.
Error's message is displayed in `StatusBar` at bottom of Form.

This information is displayed before clicking on `SAVE` button that generates an SQL `UPDATE` command.

Code used that call `PushColumnConstraints` method is following

```vbnet
    Public Sub FillPanel()
    
        SQL =
    <sql-select>
    
        SELECT code_pays
              ,nom
              ,code_pays_short
              ,default_devise
          FROM pays
          ORDER BY nom
            
    </sql-select>
    
        Dim cmd As New NpgsqlCommand(SQL, cn)
        Dim dr As NpgsqlDataReader
    
        Try
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Catch ex As Exception
            ThrowException(ex)
        End Try
    
        Call PushColumnConstraints(dr)
```