# Need list of columns (fields) in a SQlite table within Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I'm building a query application in VS 2012 in which the user drills down by sequentially selecting the `Database`, then `Table`, then `Column` for the search. `Database` and `Table` selection work fine. `Column` selection not-so-much.

`Table` selection is the following SQL query Command String:

```
Dim ThisSQLcs As String = "SELECT `name` FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table';"
```

Similar syntax for getting `Column` data does not work (`type = "column"`) because there are no column/field types in `sqlite_master`. I have seen suggestions in other posts that work from the CLI (.schema `tablename`) or something about `PROGMA table_info('table_name')`, but neither of those work in this VS / VB context.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

-larry

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12161051/284240

Comment: What happens when you run `PRAGMA table_info` (with the [correct syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info))?

Comment: CL,
I tried both of the following, which produce SQlite exception errors:
Dim ThisSQLCommandString As String = "progma table_info('dxlog')"
Dim ThisSQLCommandString As String = "progma table_info(dxlog)"

But upon more experimentation, ALL of the PROGMA statements produce similar errors. Am I missing some core SQlite component that enable PROGMA?

Comment: <embarassed> Just noticed I was mis-spelling PRAGMA.