# How to retrieve real column name of aliased column

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, alias

I need to get the real column name from DataTable which I filled it by `FillSchema()` method,
this is the query I used `(SELECT ID AS [SNO],CATEG_NAME AS [Category] FROM Categories)`

```
        var dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID AS [SNO],CATEG_NAME AS [Category] FROM Categories",conn);
        da.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Source);
        dt.FillBySql(sql);
```

When I check `dt.columns` I find that there are 2 columns with the same alias name which mentioned in query. What can I do to get the real column `names(id, categ_name)`?

Comment: Why do you use aliases if you don't want them? It would be easy to `SELECT * FROM Categories` to get all column names. Another option is `ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12161051/284240 Another option is using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table in the database. http://stackoverflow.com/a/600457/284240

Comment: i used aliases to make caption for each field shown in data grid view and also need to retrieve the real column names to use them in another vital task

Comment: note that when i used ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly) it returned schema table contains every thing about each column in the mentioned query but unfortunately it can't identify aliased columns and give me
ColumnName = SNO ,,, BaseColumnName = SNO ,,, IsAliased =

Answer (score 1):

I tried to add one column with the name same as alias column name but just let it blank. [see column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCOBu.png)

then I execute this query:

```
SELECT 
    status_action,
    isread, 
    CONCAT( 
        FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(work_given, sysdate())) / 24), 
        ' days, ', 
        MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(work_given, sysdate())), 24), 
        ' hours, ', 
        MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(work_given, sysdate())), 
        ' minutes') **as** **workgivendays** 
from progressreport
```

And then I call it use `MySqlDataReader`
like this :

MySqlDataReader mdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
workgivendays =  mdr.GetString("workgivendays");
and it works

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your best bet is to alter them in C#, not alias them in SQL. This is not a best practice, but this workaround has worked for me.

On a databound datagridview, you have to change the underlying datatable. This sample will change the name of the column from 'ID' to 'SNO'. Make sure you alter a copy the table, so the original remains unchanged.

```
var dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID,CATEG_NAME AS [Category] FROM Categories",conn);
da.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Source);

dt.FillBySql(sql);
DataTable clonedWithColumnsChanged= dt.Copy();
clonedWithColumnsChanged.Columns["ID"].ColumnName = "SNO";
dgvReports.DataSource = clonedWithColumnsChanged;
```

Comment: this solution don't solve my problem because i try to develop custom DataGridView and my target is to simplify everything ,, in my case i need to extract the real column names to generate Insert and Update Queries automatically based on extracted column names

Comment: You could do inserts and Updates with a stored procedures.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-to-keeping-sql-in-stored-procs-versus-code