# About fetching data from datatable to gridviewin c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get column names for particular data table.
I tried with this code.

```
datagridFieldCreation.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Add_Information ", con);
sda.Fill(dt);
datagridFieldCreation.DataSource = dt;
```

I am getting full data that is there in table. But I want only column names to be displayed one by one. Can any one help me out??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wy5a0f%28v=vs.100%29):

```
DataTable schema = null;
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    using (var schemaCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Add_Information", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var reader = schemaCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))
        {
            schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
        }
    }
}

datagridFieldCreation.DataSource = schema;
```

[SchemaOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior%28v=vs.100%29):

> The query returns column information only. When using SchemaOnly, the
>   .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server precedes the statement
>   being executed with SET FMTONLY ON.

The column name is in the first column of every row.

```
foreach (DataRow col in schema.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ColumnName={0}", col.Field<String>("ColumnName"));
}
```

Adpated from: [Using GetSchemaTable() to retrieve only column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160976/using-getschematable-to-retrieve-only-column-names)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`SELECT * FROM YOURTABLENAME WHERE 0=1`

Comment: Could you add some additional explanation along with your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes for sure, it is simple query which has a conditional statement which is always returning false, so each time you execute the query no rows will be extracted and only columns you will get so you can easily put up these columns in you DataGridView.