# C# SQL parameter limitations?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL command in my .Net application:

```
sqlCommand.Text = "DECLARE @method NVARCHAR(MAX);
                   SET @method = ' WITH selectRows AS (SELECT *, row=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT 1)) FROM [' + @param + ']) SELECT ' + @param_2 + ' FROM selectRows WHERE row BETWEEN 0 AND 30;'
                   EXEC(@method);";
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", tableName);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_2", columnString);
```

Whenever '@param_2' is long the query won't execute. Lets say the column string looks like this:

```
[class],[partnr],[accessoriesidentifier],[canbelinedup],[certificate],[certificate_ce],[certificate_ul],[certificate_vde],[codeletter],[construction],[craftcooling],[craftelectro],[craftfluid],[crafthydraulic],[craftlubrication],[craftmechanic],[craftpneumatic],[craftprocess],[create],[depth],[depthspacingfront],[depthspacingrear],[description1],[description2],[description3],[discount],[ecabinetmacro],[erpnr],[externaldocument1],[externaldocument2],[externaldocument3],[externalplacement],[functiongroup],[graphicmacro],[groupnumber],[groupsymbolmacro],[height],[heightspacingabove],[heightspacingbelow],[identcode],[identtype],[isaccessory],[lastchange],[lifetime],[macro3d],[maintenance],[manufacturer],[mountinglocation],[mountingspace],[note],[ordernr],[packagingprice1],[packagingprice2],[packagingquantity],[picturefile],[piecetype],[priceunit],[productgroup],[productsubgroup],[producttopgroup],[purchaseprice1],[purchaseprice2],[quantityunit],[reportid],[salesprice1],[salesprice2],[snapheight],[snapheightmiddleoffset],[spare],[stress],[supplier],[terminal],[typenr],[uniqueid],[usage],[wear],[weight],[width],[widthspacingleft],[widthspacingright],[barcount],[bardistance],[bargeometry],[barmountingplatedistance],[bottompaneldepth],[bottompaneldistance],[bottompanelprojectionback],[bottompanelprojectionfront],[bottompanelprojectionleft],[bottompanelprojectionright],[busbarholderpartnr],[busbarholdervariant],[busbarrailpartnr],[busbarrailvariant],[deliverylength],[dooroffsetright],[dooroffsettop],[doorthickness],[doortrabbet],[doortype],[hingeposition],[insertpointoffsetx],[profiledepth],[profiledistance],[profileheight],[rearpaneldistance],[rearpaneldpepth],[rearpanelprojectionbottom],[rearpanelprojectionleft],[rearpanelprojectionright],[rearpanelprojectiontop],[sidepaneldepth],[sidepaneldistance],[sidepanelprojectionback],[sidepanelprojectionbottom],[sidepanelprojectionfront],[sidepanelprojectiontop],[toppaneldistance],[toppaneldpepth],[toppanelprojectionback],[toppanelprojectionfront],[toppanelprojectionleft],[toppanelprojectionright],[vprofiledepth],[vprofilewidth],[wallthickness],[widthbottom],[widthtop],[variant],[adjustrange],[adressrange],[advancecontacts],[airgap],[assemblyspreaded],[awgfrom],[awgtill],[bendingradius],[cabledesignation],[cabledisplayform],[cablelength],[cabletype],[cableweight],[coding],[color],[connection],[connectioncrosssection],[connectiondesignation],[connectionmethod],[contactarrangement],[contacttype],[coppernumber],[creepagedistance],[crosssectionfrom],[crosssectiontill],[currentcsa],[currentiec],[currentul],[degofprotection],[design],[doordepth],[doorheight],[doormountingspace],[doorwidth],[electricalcurrent],[electricalpower],[firmwareversion],[flow],[holdingpower],[innerdiameter],[intrinsicsafety],[material],[norm],[outerdiameter],[paneldepth],[panelheight],[panelmountingspace],[panelwidth],[pincount],[pipeclass],[plcdeviceid],[plcisbuscoupler],[plcisbusdistributor],[plciscpu],[plcispowersupply],[plcobjectdescription],[plctype],[powerdissipation],[pressure],[pressurelevel],[shortcircuitresistant],[standardinvers],[strokelength],[symbolfile],[symbolnr],[technicalcharacteristics],[thread],[triggercurrent],[voltage],[voltagecsa],[voltageiec],[voltagetype],[voltageul],[widthrating],[wirecount],[wirecrosssection],[wirecrosssectionanddiameter],[wirecrosssectionunit],[variant_1],[characteristics],[connectiondescription],[connectiondesignation_1],[description],[functiondefcategory],[functiondefgroup],[functiondefid],[hasled],[hasplugadapter],[idx1],[idx2],[intrinsicsafety_1],[nesteddevicetag],[pos],[safetyrelevant],[symbol],[symbolmacro],[terminalfunction],[terminalnr],[partnr_1],[variant_2],[count],[parentvariant],[pos_1],[22235.0],[22236.0],[22237.0],[22238.0],[22239.0],[22240.0],[22241.0],[22196.1],[22196.2],[22158.1],[22158.2],[22159.1],[22159.2],[22195.1],[22195.2],[22228.1],[22228.2],[22228.3],[22228.4],[22228.5],[22228.6],[22228.7],[22228.8],[22228.9],[22228.10]
```

The query won't execute on the server (SQL server 2005). When I remove 10 columns, the query executes without any issues. I used the sql profiler to look for any problems that the sql server receives from my application, but no problems found there. I'm really confused why it isn't working.

What I try to achieve is to get a result set of all the columns from the database table WITHOUT the row column. Because if I change the SELECT @param_2 to SELECT *, i'll get all the columns plus and extra column showing the row number. To get rid of this row number I thought I just send all the column names to the SELECT statement of the query. However I'm now running in the above problem. I hope someone knows a solution that either solves the problem from above or how to get a result set of all the columns excluding the row number with a better query than I'm using.

P.s: the size of the ('failing') column string is 3612 characters.
I do not have too much experience with SQL itself. So excuse me if I'm making silly mistakes.

EDIT:
The column names depends on the user, so they can't be hardcoded in the query.

Comment: Whoops typo, changed it to 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither your string literals nor your passed parameters are, themselves, of type `nvarchar(max)`. You're therefore falling foul of this remark about [string concatenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx):

> If the result of the concatenation of strings exceeds the limit of 8,000 bytes, the result is truncated. However, if at least one of the strings concatenated is a large value type, truncation does not occur.

What I'd probably do is change the parameter to explicitly be an `nvarchar(max)`:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@param_2", SqlDbType.NVarChar,-1).Value =
     columnString;
```

Alternatively you could fix it with:

```
SET @method = CONVERT(nvarchar(max),
' WITH selectRows AS (SELECT *, row=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT 1)) FROM [') + ...
```

Comment: When I tell the parameter to be a nvarchar(max) it works! Thanks! I'm curious though why it isn't working when I don't specify the size? Because the sql profiler shows me the nvarchar is the same size as the column string.

Comment: @WonderTiger - because it's only 3612 characters long and so `AddWithValue` decides to send it as an `nchar(3612)` or an `nvarchar(3612)` (not sure which).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this doesn't answer the question directly but it might be helpful anyway. Why do you need to use dynamioc sql at all? Why can't you use this:

```
string sql = @"
WITH CTE AS 
( 
         SELECT   *, 
                  row=Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) 
         FROM     dbo.TableName 
SELECT [class],[partnr],[accessoriesidentifier],[canbelinedup],[certificate],[certificate_ce],[certificate_ul],[certificate_vde],[codeletter],[construction],[craftcooling],[craftelectro],[craftfluid],[crafthydraulic],[craftlubrication],[craftmechanic],[craftpneumatic],[craftprocess],[create],[depth],[depthspacingfront],[depthspacingrear],[description1],[description2],[description3],[discount],[ecabinetmacro],[erpnr],[externaldocument1],[externaldocument2],[externaldocument3],[externalplacement],[functiongroup],[graphicmacro],[groupnumber],[groupsymbolmacro],[height],[heightspacingabove],[heightspacingbelow],[identcode],[identtype],[isaccessory],[lastchange],[lifetime],[macro3d],[maintenance],[manufacturer],[mountinglocation],[mountingspace],[note],[ordernr],[packagingprice1],[packagingprice2],[packagingquantity],[picturefile],[piecetype],[priceunit],[productgroup],[productsubgroup],[producttopgroup],[purchaseprice1],[purchaseprice2],[quantityunit],[reportid],[salesprice1],[salesprice2],[snapheight],[snapheightmiddleoffset],[spare],[stress],[supplier],[terminal],[typenr],[uniqueid],[usage],[wear],[weight],[width],[widthspacingleft],[widthspacingright],[barcount],[bardistance],[bargeometry],[barmountingplatedistance],[bottompaneldepth],[bottompaneldistance],[bottompanelprojectionback],[bottompanelprojectionfront],[bottompanelprojectionleft],[bottompanelprojectionright],[busbarholderpartnr],[busbarholdervariant],[busbarrailpartnr],[busbarrailvariant],[deliverylength],[dooroffsetright],[dooroffsettop],[doorthickness],[doortrabbet],[doortype],[hingeposition],[insertpointoffsetx],[profiledepth],[profiledistance],[profileheight],[rearpaneldistance],[rearpaneldpepth],[rearpanelprojectionbottom],[rearpanelprojectionleft],[rearpanelprojectionright],[rearpanelprojectiontop],[sidepaneldepth],[sidepaneldistance],[sidepanelprojectionback],[sidepanelprojectionbottom],[sidepanelprojectionfront],[sidepanelprojectiontop],[toppaneldistance],[toppaneldpepth],[toppanelprojectionback],[toppanelprojectionfront],[toppanelprojectionleft],[toppanelprojectionright],[vprofiledepth],[vprofilewidth],[wallthickness],[widthbottom],[widthtop],[variant],[adjustrange],[adressrange],[advancecontacts],[airgap],[assemblyspreaded],[awgfrom],[awgtill],[bendingradius],[cabledesignation],[cabledisplayform],[cablelength],[cabletype],[cableweight],[coding],[color],[connection],[connectioncrosssection],[connectiondesignation],[connectionmethod],[contactarrangement],[contacttype],[coppernumber],[creepagedistance],[crosssectionfrom],[crosssectiontill],[currentcsa],[currentiec],[currentul],[degofprotection],[design],[doordepth],[doorheight],[doormountingspace],[doorwidth],[electricalcurrent],[electricalpower],[firmwareversion],[flow],[holdingpower],[innerdiameter],[intrinsicsafety],[material],[norm],[outerdiameter],[paneldepth],[panelheight],[panelmountingspace],[panelwidth],[pincount],[pipeclass],[plcdeviceid],[plcisbuscoupler],[plcisbusdistributor],[plciscpu],[plcispowersupply],[plcobjectdescription],[plctype],[powerdissipation],[pressure],[pressurelevel],[shortcircuitresistant],[standardinvers],[strokelength],[symbolfile],[symbolnr],[technicalcharacteristics],[thread],[triggercurrent],[voltage],[voltagecsa],[voltageiec],[voltagetype],[voltageul],[widthrating],[wirecount],[wirecrosssection],[wirecrosssectionanddiameter],[wirecrosssectionunit],[variant_1],[characteristics],[connectiondescription],[connectiondesignation_1],[description],[functiondefcategory],[functiondefgroup],[functiondefid],[hasled],[hasplugadapter],[idx1],[idx2],[intrinsicsafety_1],[nesteddevicetag],[pos],[safetyrelevant],[symbol],[symbolmacro],[terminalfunction],[terminalnr],[partnr_1],[variant_2],[count],[parentvariant],[pos_1],[22235.0],[22236.0],[22237.0],[22238.0],[22239.0],[22240.0],[22241.0],[22196.1],[22196.2],[22158.1],[22158.2],[22159.1],[22159.2],[22195.1],[22195.2],[22228.1],[22228.2],[22228.3],[22228.4],[22228.5],[22228.6],[22228.7],[22228.8],[22228.9],[22228.10]
FROM   CTE
WHERE  row BETWEEN @StartRow AND  @EndRow;";

using(var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@StartRow", SqlDbType.int).Value = 1; 
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@EndRow", SqlDbType.int).Value = 30;
    // ...
}
```

---

Since the column-names are specified by the user you cannot add them as parameter without dynamic sql. But you know all valid column-names, so you could check if all are valid. If you don't know all columns of a the table, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12161051/284240) and use `reader.GetSchemaTable` to load all columns on application start.

Then you can simply add it to the sql:

```
string sql = @"
WITH CTE AS 
( 
         SELECT   *, 
                  row=Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) 
         FROM     dbo.TableName 
SELECT {0}
FROM   CTE
WHERE  row BETWEEN @StartRow AND  @EndRow;";

sql = string.Format(sql, string.Join(",", columnList));
```

Comment: The column names change depending on the user, so they can't be hardcoded in the query. Atleast that's the way I thought, maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: @WonderTiger: does the table also have to be dynamic or do you know it at compile time?

Comment: Yes it is dynamic. The table is some kind of tempory table to match excel, csv, tekst, etc. with eachother.

Comment: @WonderTiger: then you should again edit your question to clarify that. Meanwhile i've provided a solution if your table would be known.