# Is it possible to get the length of the SQL column through SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, sql, clr

Using SqlDataReader, I am able to get both the column name and SQL datatype, but I can't seem to find a way to get length, precision, or scale. Is there another way I can get this data for each column?

code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public class StoredProcedures
{
 [SqlProcedure]
    public static void CLRExec(SqlString query)
    {
        SqlContext.Pipe.Send(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " -- " + query.ToString());
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
        {
            string sQuery = query.ToString();

            // Create the record and specify the metadata for the columns.
            SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord(
                new SqlMetaData("col1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100),
                new SqlMetaData("col2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100));

            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sQuery, connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            //DataTable table = reader.GetSchemaTable();


            // Mark the begining of the result-set.
            SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsStart(record);

            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                record.SetString(0, reader.GetName(i).ToString());
                record.SetString(1, reader.GetDataTypeName(i).ToString());

                // Send the row back to the client.
                SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsRow(record);
            }

            SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try the schema = reader.GetSchemaTable(); to return all the schema information?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using GetSchemaTable() to retrieve only column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160976/using-getschematable-to-retrieve-only-column-names)

Comment: @BrunoXavier I tried going that route, but it ended up causing more frustration and confusion than it was worth. It started with CREATE ASSEMBLY failures because of static fields in System.Data.DataSetExtensions & at this point I'm not about to write a second assembly to fix it lol

Comment: I took a further look into it & it appears that I can't use the col.Fields<string>('...') things because they're not supported on SQL Server. Would you happen to know of any alternatives? @BrunoXavier